# Which of these services require an internet connection

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I would just like to confirm this because on my device, there are inconsistencies...

From these operations, which of them do/do not require an internet connection on the device.

1. View achievements using Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent();
2. View leaderboards using Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderBoardsIntent();
3. Submitting a score on a leaderboard
4. Signing in to google play games using the following code...

   ```
       mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
       // leaderboard and rate listeners dependent on signed in or not
       GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSignInSucceeded() {
               signingInText.setText("Signed in as: " + Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mHelper.getApiClient()).getDisplayName());
               leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       startActivityForResult(
                               Games.Leaderboards
                                       .getLeaderboardIntent(
                                               mHelper.getApiClient(),
                                               getString(R.string.leaderboard_highest_score)),
                               1);
                   }

               });
               rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       launchMarket();
                   }

               });
               achievementsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements
                               .getAchievementsIntent(mHelper.getApiClient()),
                               2);
                   }

               });
           }

           @Override
           public void onSignInFailed() {
               signingInText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               if (mHelper.hasSignInError()) {
                   mHelper.showFailureDialog();
               }
               leaderboardButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Toast.makeText(appContext,
                               "You must be signed in to view the leaderboard",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               });
               achievementsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Toast.makeText(appContext,
                               "You must be signed in to view your achievements",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               });
           }
   ```

Comment: All of them are require internet connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** sign-in to Play Games service **without** an active internet connection, but only if you have previously signed-in (i.e. chosen an account) and have not signed out - via either the `mHelper.signOut()` method (in your app) or from within the Play Games app.

You can unlock **and** view achievements as long as you are signed-in - so the sign-in described above **must** have been successful.

Similarly for leaderboards, if you are signed-in, you can submit scores, but the leaderboard display won't be updated with the score until you are connected - you can view leaderboards, but they will show "no connection" messages.

Synching and cloud saves (obviously) do not work without an active internet connection.

The key here is that nothing is possible unless you can sign-in - if that fails then all the rest **will fail**. However, as long as you can sign-in, it is fairly functional without an active connection.

EDIT:
Also be sure that if sign-in fails, you cache leaderboard scores and unlocked achievements (to some form of persistent storage, ex. file) and post/unlock them during the next successful sign-in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip in your edit: I implemented that and it's a very nice feature.

Comment: Happy to help. It is much better to implement the caching feature early in development, using a management class or wrapper functions. That way you always post/unlock using it and don't have to go hunting around and replacing calls later on :) Also, I found that keeping the player's highest leaderboard score on hand is beneficial for display purposes - you can show them their best score at any time without having to look it up through the play service. Just be sure then to also **get** the leaderboard score when signing it (in case they got a better score on another device).

Comment: Yeah I just stored it in shared preferences and do a check to see if its better than their leaderboard score the next time they go online. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Achievements can be viewed (and unlocked) offline. Once online again, the achievement state will be synced with Google Play Games Services. See [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements).

Viewing and submitting scores to leaderboards require an internet connection.

Signing into Google Play Games Services also requires an internet connection.